# How to send SMS text message from Flash (AS3) iPhone app

Tags: iphone, android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I am developing an iPhone app with Adobe Flash and I can't figure out how to send a text message directly from within the app.

You can open a new SMS window as explained [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_uris.html)

```
public function sms():void
{
  const callURL:String="sms:1234567890";
  var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
  navigateToURL(targetURL);
}
```

When the function is run on a phone, the default SMS client is launched with the telephone number already entered

But is it possible to send an SMS text message without opening the SMS client?

Or is it only possible by calling an external server?

Comment: Although the question is mostly aimed at Air for iPhone, I will certainly port the app to Android as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are pretty much your only options:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_uris.html

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_SMS_Texting_with_Flex_and_Air-12007.html

https://sites.google.com/site/freesmsuk/send-free-sms-with-flex

You'll have to test if any of these methods work on iPhone, as I know that the first method does indeed work on android.

Comment: So it seems that currently it isn't possible with Air to send an SMS text message without opening the default SMS client on the phone. Any ideas if this is going to happen in a future update of the Air platform?

Comment: For android or iphone? Knowing adobe's typical approach, probably not. A lot of times, when it comes to interacting with the native system adobe is working on they are very "tip-toe-ish", or in other words, they don't want to give any functionality that has any potential to be exploited. However, I do know that for android it is possible to hack android APK's made with flash to extend them and implement native processes, basically doing anything. However, I don't believe this knowledge is yet public... (cont)

Comment: An adobe employee has sent me drafts of a paper he is writing on this, but has asked me NOT to distribute it under any circumstance. All I can tell you is that it is possible and looks as though it will be published soon, so keep googling. :) "extending AIR for android"

Comment: James Ward has put up a good article on this on his blog. http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/

It would be nice to be able to do the same thing on iPhone as well.

Comment: Yeah that's who I was talking about in my comment. Pretty exciting stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Future versions of Adobe AIR on mobile are going to have support of Native Extensions. Using this, developers could make use of any of the native mobile features. You can join the Adobe Prerelease program for more insights into this and more future features of AIR

Comment: Any change on this? I used an app that sent a text message on Android. It did not open the default text messaging program. I know how to send a text but I just need to know how to get the users phone number.

Answer (score 0):

For Adobe Air as3 Android

```
public function gotoSms(e:MouseEvent):void{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:05432314403?body=Message text hello"));
}
```

sms:phone number

?body=message area

Regards